# Method body for a generic Obj-C method with a completion block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I love using `animateWithDuration:options:completion`. I have come across a few situations where I could really use this for my own scenario without an animation, but I am having difficulty writing the method body out. Obviously I can't just look at the `UIView`'s code, only it's signatures.

Here was my attempt (I may have the method signatures all messed up too):

```
.h
+(void)performGenericBlock:(void(^)(BOOL))code actionWhenDone:(void(^)(void))action;

.m
+(void)performGenericBlock:(void(^)(BOOL))code actionWhenDone:(void(^)(void))action
{
   //Kind of lost here - here is psuedocode
   [do stuff:^(BOOL done){action}];
}
```

Basically I want to accomplish:

Perform the first block of code, when it is done, do the second block of code.

Comment: If I missed something to make this question more clear, please leave a comment and explain how I can improve it when you down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need two arguments, you should be able to just write the code in the original block.

In the following examples, assume we want to first call [self.test foo1] then [self.test foo2].

The simplest solution is to not create a new method at all. Simply call your code:

```
[self.test foo1];
[self.test foo2];
```

foo2 will be performed after foo1.

The second simplest solution is to create the function with only one argument:

```
[ViewController performGenericBlock:^{
    [self.test foo1];
    [self.test foo2];
}];
```

If you really do need 2 arguments, you would do the following:

```
[ViewController performGenericBlock:^{
    [self.test foo1];
} actionWhenDone:^{
    [self.test foo2];
}];
```

... and define the method like so:

```
+ (void)performGenericBlock:(void(^)(void))code actionWhenDone:(void(^)(void))action {
    code();
    action();
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I was going for. Basically when I was thinking of this, I was opening a URL in safari....and wanted to change the frame of some UI stuff when it completed. Thanks for the help, tested and work and will accept when SO lets me.